# Video is not playing after downloading from google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am downloading a video file from my google drive to my phone from my application. But the problem is that when I download the file, the file didn't play. I don't know what is the problem with file. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Please specifiy more clearly what is wrong. Did the file download correctly, Is there an error message, Which player are you using, What video (codec?), Did you program the downloader or is this just a question on how to use an App?

Comment: The file is downloaded correctly. There is no error message in response, just get an url only to download the file which I have selected. I did the program to download the file from my google drive, the file downloaded successfully but it didn't play in my device. @Thommy